How to establish sftp connection in vsphere client
I have been requested to establish SFTP connections using vSphere client.
Initially, I tried to launch a web console, but after some questions about disk partitioning the screen just went blank. Thus, I would like to ask if you know any way to establish an SFTP connection in vSphere client.
We are a university lab and we want to share data by establishing SFTP connections in a virtual machine.
 
P.S. If you think that this is not the suitable site of stack exchange for this question, could you propose one?


I have been requested to establish sftp connections using vsphere client.

The vSphere client is about providing a virtual connection to the console. Screen, keyboard, mouse, and even virtual USB/DVD devices. But not file transfer - that's not its purpose.
If you need file transfer (for example using SFTP) to the client, then use an SFTP client or server on that client.
